# What do I need to do in order to save PDF file in Android 10 and above?

Tags: java, android, save, itext, android-10.0

I'm using ItextG to fill out a pdf form and save the file but it does not work for Android 10 and above Devices. Can someone tell me what do I need to change in the PdfStamper or the dst string to make it work.

````
InputStream src = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pdf_fillable);
                String dst = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/client.pdf";

                try {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
                            new FileOutputStream(dst));
                    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();```
````

Comment: _"...it does not work for Android 10 and above Devices."_ How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: For Android 11: `String dst = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)  + "/MyFolder/client.pdf";` Be shure to create MyFolder before use.

Comment: For Android 10: request legacy external storage in manifest file.